# Show extra icon in Unity notification area (14.04, Copy Agent)

Tags: unity, 14.04, copy.com

I have installed [Copy Agent](https://www.copy.com) but when I launch it the icon doesn't show up in the notification area ...

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

please try

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Comment: I have just tried, log out and log in again ... but nothing is shown